# Any pictorial depiction of Naaraacha Mudra?

Tags: karma, tantra, mudra

Any pictorial depiction with scriptural Pramāṇa of Naaraacha Mudra while doing Bhuta Uchchatanam ? It's done along with Choṭikā Mudra